# How to type ŵ (w circumflex) on an external bluetooth keyboard on iPad

Tags: ipad, special-characters

How to produce the character **ŵ** on **iPad** using **external keyboard**? I could type other special characters like ö, ü and ä but not ŵ. I typed a lot in a language, where the character **ŵ** frequently occurs.

I tried the *Text Replacement* (Settings > Keyboard > Text Replacement), however the iPad replaces the whole word instead of a single character.

Answer (score -1):

Until you find the ultimate answer, you can simple paste a copied ŵ (created with the virtual keyboard) each time you need it in a text. I use this until I find a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. There are a lot of that character (together with ö) in my monther tounge almost every two words. So constant copying will only get so far.